# How do you pump Creosote Oil out of a Coke Oven

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

My Coke Oven has about 30k's worth of Creosote Oil, which I want to store in a tank, but I cannot get it out. I've tried putting Fluiducts all around it and it doesn't come out at all. Is there something special I need to do to get the oil out?

Answer (score 3):

As said in the Feed The Beast wiki, you can take the creosote oil out with a bucket. Here's the quote:

> Placing a Bucket in the Coke Oven's inventory (on the right) will fill the Bucket with Creosote Oil. Wooden Waterproof Pipes can also be used to take Creosote Oil into Tanks. The Coke Oven will not function if the inventory of the Coke Oven is full with Creosote Oil. Each time a coal is burned to produce a Coal Coke, 500 mB (half a bucket) of Creosete Oil will be produced.

If you absolutly want to use a pipe to get it out, you need to use Buildcraft pipes, otherwise it wont work.

Here is a video tutorial explaining how you can do it.

Answer (score 3):

Just now discovered a way to do this without any extra mods, like BuildCraft:

1. Place a pump adjancent to the place you want the oven to be; do *not* place the oven itself yet. It won't require power, so don't bother with connectors.
2. Use the Engineer's Hammer once on the pump on the side where the oven will be. It will turn blue - it's the input side now.
3. Use the hammer again on any other side, twice. It will first turn blue, then orange - it's the output side now. You may now place fluid pipes here and stretch them to whenever you want - tanks work perfectly for that purpose.
4. Build the actual oven and activate with the hammer, as described on it's page in the manual.
5. Supply the pump with a redstone signal - placing a lever on it and toggling it on will suffice.

Done! The creosote oil is now going to whenever you want it to. Placing the pump first was necessary because later the oven would obstruct its clickable side.

Hope that helped. :)

Answer (score 2):

Things to check:

1. Were the fluiducts set to extract?
2. Were they powered by redstone?
3. were they set so that redstone enabled them, or were they set so the redstone disabled them?

Answer (score 1):

I have pumped creosote oil from the left and right sides in several packs.  I've used Fluiducts, Buildcraft waterproof wooden pipes and EnderIO Fluid Conduits.  Never had any problems.  The problems come when the tech you are using isn't configured right.

In your case your Fluiducts would need to be set to extract.  Basically hit the bigger part attached to the side of the Coke Oven with a wrench or crescent hammer until you see an arrow head facing away from the oven.  This is explicit extract mode.  Then you either need to install a Pneumatic Servo and configure it to ignore redstone, or you need to place lever below/above the arrow on the pipe and turn the lever on.  A redstone torch would do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

On the advanced coke oven, the liquid pull point  is the hole at the bottom of the large plate.  A servo and some fluiducts will draw the creosote out.